# Is there a good tut on displaying/editing db data in a wxGrid

Tags: python, sqlite, wxpython

I'm using wxPython to write a program, backed by an sqlite3 database. I would like to display the data from one table on the grid and allow inline editing and such.

Google found me some tutorials and I have something more or less working, based around wxPyGridTableBase. Data is loaded there and such and all works rather fine.

I have more problems with the sizing of the grid and columns and such. But I could figure it out I guess.

Anyway I was wondering if there are any tutorials out there I missed on the grid. Some are too complex for what I need, others too easy. None are not about data stored in a database. Know any?

Or maybe someone can post a good working example in the answers?